# Changing the limit variable

Tags: limits, substitution

let r >0 with  ;

$f$ : $(0,r) \mapsto \mathbb{R} $

$F$ : $ (\frac{1}{r} , \infty) \mapsto \mathbb{R} $

$F(x)= f(\frac{1}{x}) $

show that :$   \lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x) = L \Leftrightarrow  lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = L$

so can  solve it like that   : 
first : :$   \lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x) = L  \Rightarrow  lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = L$

we  know already  that , $  \lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x) $= L 
let it be then T >0 so that $ T = \frac{1}{x} $
$\lim_{x \to \infty } \frac{1}{x} = \lim_{T \downarrow 0 } T $
then $\lim_{x \to \infty } f(\frac{1}{x}) = \lim_{T \downarrow 0} f(T)= L $

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$X>A>0 \iff 0<\frac{1}{X}<\frac{1}{A}=\eta$$